# Predicting the average number of transitions given a frequency and a set size?

Tags: statistics

Say I wanted to predict the number of Software Engineers in a given year that change their job.

The total number of Software Engineers in a given market is readily available (4.4 million in the US), as are retention rates for companies (conservatively, an average of 3 years).

So, an average engineer will change jobs every 3 years or more. It feels like I should be fairly trivially able to project a number of software engineers who change jobs in a given year given this data, but, for the life of me, I don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 4.4mil divided by 3 years is about 1.46 mil per year

Comment: lol I thought it might be that but seemed to be way too easy. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

In [queueing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law), **Little's Formula** is $L = \lambda W,$ where $L$ is average number of customers waiting, $\lambda$ is rate of service (customers/time), and $W$ is average service time.

You have $L = 4.4$ million and $W = 3\,$ yrs, so $\lambda = 4.4\; \mathrm{million}/3\, \mathrm{yrs} = 1.47$ million a year.

This is the same as in @JMoravitz's Comment, but with a "Name" put to it.
Are you getting ready to study queueing theory?